# How to pass data to Controller only when Submit button is Clicked?

Tags: database, codeigniter

Data is added to database in null values when page is refreshed. I want to pass them only when the submit button is clicked. How to perform it?

> View

My Code in View is as follows:

```
   <form name ="userinput" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/patient/periodicalExaminationChart" method="post">

<table width="600" height="200" >

<tr><td>Vitality :</td> <td><select><option>Positive</option><option>Negative </option></select></td></tr>
<tr><td>Recesson :</td> <td><input type="=text" name="form_recesson"></t></td></tr>
<tr><td>Fucation :</td> <td><input type ="text" name="form_fucation"></td><td><img id="toothImage" src="" style="position:absolute; "></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mobility :</td> <td><input type="=text" name="form_mobility"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Pocket Depth:</td> <td><input type ="text" name="form_pocketDepth"></td></tr>
</table>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save Details</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Reset Details</button>
</form>
```

> Controller

```
$this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('Header');
        $this->load->view('Patient/periodical_exam');
        $this->load->view('Footer');
        $this->load->model('patient_model');

         $form_data = $this->input->post();
         $data = array(
         'recesson'  => $this->input->post("form_recesson"),
         'fucation'  =>$this->input->post("form_fucation"),
         'mobility'  =>$this->input->post("form_mobility"), 
         'pocketDepth'  => $this->input->post("form_pocketDepth")
         );

         $this->patient_model->save_pExamChart($data);
```

Comment: You should go and read up on the Codeigniter user guide regarding form validation. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#form-validation-tutorial

Comment: I would suggest you use a controller method to open the page as a url, and a separate controller method for the form. I have never seen both put together, nor do i think they should be

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('patient_model'); // put this in construct method  
 function index()
 {
    if(!$_POST)
    {
      $this->load->view('Header');
      $this->load->view('Patient/periodical_exam');
      $this->load->view('Footer');
    }
    else
    {

     $form_data = $this->input->post();
     $data = array(
     'recesson'  => $this->input->post("form_recesson"),
     'fucation'  =>$this->input->post("form_fucation"),
     'mobility'  =>$this->input->post("form_mobility"), 
     'pocketDepth'  => $this->input->post("form_pocketDepth")
     );

     $this->patient_model->save_pExamChart($data);
     redirect("controller_name"); // your index function 
    }
}
```